# Android P, Play Button of Video in Webview is not working

Tags: android, html, video, webview

My android app play video in webview using html5 video tags. It works fine till my users upgrade to Android 9. Since then, we cannot click on the play button of the videos. 
We are able to click on the Mute or to move the seek bar of the video.

Did anyone experience the same issue? And is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just to update, below code solved my problem:

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible clear-text issue. Android 9 disables clear-text on webviews by default. You can print console messages to logcat to confirm (overrite onConsoleMessage() in a WebChromeClient), or just ensure you are using all https.

This is only valid if the webview is loading a URL, not local content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually we are using Local content so still not able to fix it.